# How do I identify all the students who have passed?

Tags: if-not-exists

Suppose I have a Table `student` and a Table `exam` which tracks all the exams a student has taken, how do I find all the students who have passed or not taken any exams similar to a white-list? In this example that means students 1 and 2.

PS: `pass` flag `U` means that the status is unknown, `active` flag `N` means the exam was removed, rest of the flags are self explanatory.

Just to be very clear, the real use case is actually `assessments`, I need to figure out people who have no `pending` assessments to participate in, so that they can proceed with next set of procedures. Others would need to finish the pending items.

```
+-------------+------+
| student_idn | name |
+-------------+------+
| 1           | Mark |
| 2           | Jack |
| 3           | Jane |
| 4           | Jill |
+-------------+------+

+----------+-------------+------+--------+
| exam_idn | student_idn | pass | active |
+----------+-------------+------+--------+
| 1        | 1           | Y    | Y      |
| 2        | 1           | Y    | Y      |
| 3        | 1           | Y    | Y      |
| 4        | 2           | Y    | Y      |
| 5        | 2           | N    | N      |
| 6        | 3           | Y    | Y      |
| 7        | 3           | Y    | Y      |
| 8        | 3           | Y    | Y      |
| 9        | 3           | N    | Y      |
| 10       | 4           | U    | Y      |
+----------+-------------+------+--------+
```

I came up with this below query but is there a better way to do this? I feel that this is O(n) or O(nlogn) depending on index etc not sure (anyone knows the best possible for this) hence should be close to optimal?

```
SELECT
  *
FROM student
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT
  *
FROM exam
WHERE exam.student_idn = student.student_idn
AND pass <> 'Y'
AND active = 'Y')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you describe is known as relational division. There are basically two ways to approach it:

1. Transform for all x : p(x) to  not exists x :  not p(x)

In other words, transform students who have passed all test to students where it does not exist a test that the student did not pass. Your query in the question is an example of this.

This transformation is often referred to as `De Morgan's laws for quantifiers`. See for example:

https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/28324/proving-de-morgans-laws-for-quantifiers

2. Students who have passed the same amount of tests as there are tests. Something like:

   ```
    SELECT student_id
    FROM tests
    WHERE passed = 'y' 
    GROUP BY student_id
    HAVING COUNT(1) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT test_id) 
                       FROM tests)
   ```

I'm answering from a mobile so I can't see the question while answering, so the details of my answer is likely wrong according to your question, but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: `students who have passed all test` is not equivalent to `students where it does not exist a test that the student did not pass` in the OP's case because of the possibility of a `U` status. That is, a student could have all tests as U's. That would match the latter condition but not the former.

Comment: Besides Andriy's valid point, it doesn't look like relational division to me. There is not a specific list of exam for all students to check. Seems like each student has a separate list of exams.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
USE tempdb

CREATE TABLE dbo.Student (
  s_idn int,
  name varchar(30)
);
CREATE TABLE dbo.Exam (
  e_idn int IDENTITY,
  s_idn int,
  pass char(1),
  active char(1)
)
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.student (s_idn, name)
  VALUES (1, 'Mark'),
  (2, 'Jack'),
  (3, 'Jane'),
  (4, 'Jill')
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.Exam (s_idn, pass, active)
  VALUES (1, 'Y', 'Y')
  , (1, 'Y', 'Y')
  , (1, 'Y', 'Y')
  , (2, 'Y', 'Y')
  , (2, 'N', 'N')
  , (3, 'Y', 'Y')
  , (3, 'Y', 'Y')
  , (3, 'Y', 'Y')
  , (3, 'N', 'Y')
  , (4, 'U', 'Y')
GO

SELECT
  *
FROM dbo.Student
EXCEPT
SELECT DISTINCT
  s.*
FROM dbo.student s
INNER JOIN dbo.exam e
  ON s.s_idn = e.s_idn
  AND (e.pass <> 'Y'
  AND e.active <> 'N');
```

The following is less expensive in performance:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM dbo.student
WHERE s_idn NOT IN (SELECT s.s_idn
                    FROM dbo.student s
                    INNER JOIN dbo.exam e
                        ON s.s_idn = e.s_idn
                       AND e.pass <> 'Y'
                       AND e.active <> 'N')
```

Actually, it should be like this, this way, you do not need to join the two tables:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM dbo.student
WHERE s_idn NOT IN (SELECT s_idn
                    FROM dbo.exam e
                    WHERE e.pass <> 'Y'
                      AND e.active = 'Y')
```